# Validating XML (Not just the grammar) with Xerces against XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xerces

I am trying to write a quick-and-dirty XML validator for a project on which I'm working. I'm currently using Xerces C++.

Using a XercesDOMParser it's easy enough to validate the grammar of the xml against the provided XSD schema, but that's only part of what I want.

I want to be able to validate the values as well.

So, for example, if the XSD schema specifies that a value must be an xs:date

```
<xs:element name="DOB" type="xs:date"/>
```

But the XML just contains (for example) a random string, such as

```
<DOB>banana</DOB>
```

I would expect that to be flagged as an error.

Is this form of validation possible with Xerces?

EDIT:

This is my override of ErrorHandler:

```
class MyErrorHandler : public ErrorHandler
{
public :
    virtual void warning(const SAXParseException& exc);
    virtual void error(const SAXParseException& exc);
    virtual void fatalError(const SAXParseException& exc);
    virtual void resetErrors();
};

void MyErrorHandler::warning(const SAXParseException& exc)
{
    std::cout << "WARNING\n";
}

void MyErrorHandler::error(const SAXParseException& exc)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR\n";
}

void MyErrorHandler::fatalError(const SAXParseException& exc)
{
    char* message = xercesc::XMLString::transcode(exc.getMessage());
    std::cout << "Fatal " <<  message << " at line " << exc.getLineNumber() << " column " << exc.getColumnNumber() << std::endl;
    xercesc::XMLString::release(&message);
}
```

And this is main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        struct stat buffer;

        if ( (stat(argv[1], &buffer) == 0) && (stat(argv[2], &buffer) == 0))
        {
            try {
                XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
            }
            catch (const XMLException& toCatch) {
                return 1;
            }

            XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();
            parser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation(argv[1]);
            parser->setExitOnFirstFatalError(true);
            parser->setValidationConstraintFatal(true);
            parser->setValidationScheme(XercesDOMParser::Val_Auto);
            parser->setDoNamespaces(false);
            parser->setDoSchema(true);
            parser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);

            MyErrorHandler errorHandler;

            parser->setErrorHandler(&errorHandler);

            std::string xmlFile(argv[2]);

            try {
                parser->parse(xmlFile.c_str());
            }
            catch (const DOMException& e)
            {
                std::cout << "DOM Exception.." << std::endl;
            }
            catch (const SAXException& e)
            {
                std::cout << "SAX Exception.." << std::endl;
            }
            catch (const XMLException& e)
            {
                std::cout << "XML Exception.." << std::endl;
            }
            XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "XSD/XML file absent\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Incorrect number of arguments - Usage : " << argv[0] << " <sample schema> <sample xml>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Any XSD schema processor will validate the instance both against the "grammar" (the complex types) and against the constraints on values (the simple types). What makes you think this isn't happening?

Comment: When I hack the type, no error is reported. So the above xsd/xml doesn't generate an error.

Comment: Then I'll have to hand over to someone who knows Xerces C++ to help you.